# how to run PHP without extension in url?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

this questions was asked previously but not answered quite clearly.
i have ubuntu 14.04 server with apache2, php5 and fatfreeframework (f3) running on the www.example.com and without the f3 running on crm.example.com
i'm not using .htaccess file in both virtualhosts.
i have ssl only on the **www** website.
on the crm.example.com i manage to open the homepage (**index.php**) as http://crm.example.com/ but any other page opened as crm.example.com/page doesn't open unless i add the .php to the name of page i.e.: www.example.com/page.php
i want to be able to open all the links and pages without the .php extension.
i.e.: crm.example.com/page and crm.example.com/news and crm.example.com/report etc... prefererably without the .htaccess but if I must then ok.

Comment: http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

Comment: You can do this with mod_rewrite in apache2. If you're the server owner, you can add everything in your vhost. Otherwise you'll need a .htaccess. Read this for a tutorial: http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/